# jQuery Lightbox doesn't work with mod_rewrite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, mod-rewrite, lightbox

I just made the URLs of my page a little bit more seo-friendly with the help of mod_rewrite. Unfortunately the jQuery Lightboxes, which I open via click don't work anymore when the URL contains more than one slash.

So:
www.mywebsite.com/test => Lightboxes behind links work
www.mywebsite.com/test/1 or www.mywebsite.com/test/anothertest => Lightboxes don't work anymore

Anybody had a smiliar issue and can help?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show us your lightbox-links from your code on both sites.

I'm guessing you have a

```
 ../images/image.jpg
```

instead of

```
 ../../images/image.jpg
```

In the subfolders